# SuperUser and Close vs Migrate Criteria?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What is (are?) the criteria to determine whether a question is Closed with Off-topic reasons:

- Questions about general computing hardware and software... You may be able to get help on Super User.
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network .... belongs on Super User.

Naively, they seem like the same to me. Or perhaps one is a superset of the other. But I'm obviously missing something because I don't appreciate the distinction.

Related: if five people agree that a question is about general computing hardware and software and close it as such, why is it not migrated given there is unanimous consensus?

**EDIT**: as for the close as duplicate, please note that there is no criteria provided on the cited duplicate (I came across it earlier when searching). I'm specifically interested in the criteria that should be used to make the choice.

Related: I think its out of scope for Stack Overflow to make the choice of what constitutes "quality" for Super User. If the question fits Super User, then it should be migrated and Super User can determine what's worthy since its their site.

**Baffled**: the down votes make no sense to me. I don't understand what's so offensive or wrong with asking for the criteria. Would someone please explain it to me?

Comment: +1 I must admit I had never paid attention to the difference...

Comment: It seems like double work, but if the question truly belongs on another site (whether low quality question), I prefer it be migrated over to SU, then closed as low quality question. It is more work, but feel it is correct organization of questions. Perhaps moderators can have the power to migrate and close as low quality on the new site?

Answer (score 4):

One option migrates the post, the other does not.

Use *You may be able to get help* if the question is of *low quality* and should **not** be migrated. The close reason links to the on-topic help information on Super User, not to the homepage or question form.

*This question belongs on another site* will migrate the post if enough people agree.

Comment: This kind of begs another question.... for the person who is performing the Close, what is the difference? If the question belongs on Super User, then that's where it belongs. I don't understand the choice that follows.

Comment: @jww, agreed, if the difference is purely a quality issue, it seems pointless to suggest SU for poor quality questions (which probably shouldn't be on SU anyway). We might as well just close such poor questions here saying it's not the right subject and the asker should seek help elsewhere.

Comment: http://begthequestion.info/ @jww