# How frequently are questions migrated?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope, migration

This is related to [SuperUser and Close vs Migrate Criteria?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266869/superuser-and-close-vs-migrate-criteria).

A question was just asked that seems to be "quality" (for some definition of "quality" that's yet to be defined): [Virtual Box: Critical error while running the virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996432/virtual-box-critical-error-while-running-the-virtual-machine).

The question is well on its way to being closed as off-topic rather than closed and migrated.

**Question**: why does the question not meet the "quality" requirement for migration?

**Question**: how many Super User questions are closed as off-topic versus closed and migrated?

**Question**: does the community actually use the close and migrate feature?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the community does use the migrate option.

10k+ users have access to certain moderator tools, including statistics on migrations. In the past 90 days, 94 posts were migrated to SuperUser, with 6% of those being rejected. This includes moderator-initiated migrations, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958568/how-to-create-ubuntu-installable-iso-image-from-files?noredirect=1) for example was migrated entirely by community vote.

The post you refer to has only received *two* close votes, I'd hardly call that *well on its way*. Note that the 'belongs on another site' option is listed second-to-last however; it may be easier for many voters to just go with the very first option in the off-topic close voting menu.

Comment: *"94 posts were migrated to SuperUser"* - how many were closed for Super User without migration?

Comment: @jww: You'll have to create a [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) query for that.

Comment: *"I'd hardly call that well on its way..."* - give it time. Two close votes in 6 minutes for a question that has nothing to do with programming ....

Comment: @jww: in tags with at most 274 unique followers. Bringing it to Meta helps bring attention though.

Comment: one last question. Of the 94, how many were community consensus vs one user with super powers?

Comment: @jww: I am still trying to figure out how to query for OT reasons and count them; the posthistory table has a user column; if it is -1 then a community vote was conducted, so you should be able to query for migrations by community vote vs. moderator votes.

Comment: my bad. I was not trying to create a bunch of extra work. I thought someone might have the stats handy. Would you like me to delete the question? Its not that important, and I don't think its worth the effort.

Comment: @jww: I find it interesting enough so far. :-)

Comment: @jww: unfortunately there is not enough data in the data explorer to give you quantities. Migration stubs (the locked post left after migrating away) is deleted after a while and thus removed from the SEDE dataset, and for other closed posts the exact off-topic reason info is not available.