# Change the 'general computing hardware and software' off topic reason to one that clearly describes the 'write code for me' questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There is a close reason:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

This causes some confusion about how to properly close/migrate questions of this nature. (Exhibit [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288146/289086), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266869/289086), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252291/), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/289086), and probably many others).

From [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288147/289086):

> The comment about Super User is in the standard close reason.
>
> Some of us are unhappy that it's there as it causes problems like this, but there hasn't been a consensus reached as to what it should be replaced with.

Alrighty then, lets replace it.

---

Another item that has come up is recently is how to close questions that are problem statements without any accompanying work to be able to, well, actually work from (rather than writing everything from scratch).

Some takes on it are:

- Close it as too broad (there are too many ways to write this code)
- Unclear (it is unclear about what you are actually trying to do and the code you have)
- Off topic - debugging (programming is the art of debugging an empty file, provide is with an mcve that is something other than an empty file)
- Custom - whatever you want to type into that text area

However, these have their problems in that it isn't exactly clear what the appropriate way to close it is along with giving the proper guidance to the user to be able to fix the question.

So, lets nix the super user close reason (its a migration target) and create a new off topic reason that properly describes the "either you are asking us to write code for you, or you haven't given enough material for us to be able to work from."

Comment: I rarely use the mentioned close reason.  But I have used it a few times, and it's really perfect for questions like "How do I indent paragraphs to [margin settings] in [word processor]"?

Comment: @ryanyuyu telling someone to repost a poor question on another site really does a disservice to both that user and the other site.

Comment: It seems like you are asking two separate questions here; and the premise of your second question is faulty: ["Write this code for me" is not a reason to close a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288969/16587).

Comment: @MichaelT, but a detailed "How do I use MS-word" question is on-topic at SuperUser.  But since it has "nothing to do with programming" it's a bad SO fit.  I think that the mentioned close reason is _misued_ not poorly worded.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker there is the open question posed in others of 'it should go, but there is no consensus of what it should be replaced with'.  There is also the "how should I close the questions with just a problem statement".  I am proposing replacing the existing close reason with another that would clarify and provide proper guidance to the OP for such a question that *will* get closed as unclear or too broad, or a less applicable off topic reason.

Comment: @ryanyuyu so migrate it then.

Comment: @MichaelT Ok so you think that the wording for SuperUser is redundant since migration (for good questions) is (usually) an option.  And that this option is outdated for the low-quality question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The current off topic reasons don't provide good guidance to the OP for a homework problem (which most of these are). I am not saying that 'write code for me' is off topic, but rather that we can make use of the text for a reason to close that is grouped under 'off topic' (debugging help isn't off topic either but is also in the same grouping) that provides specific and actionable material to the poster for writing a good question. Material that is related to exactly the problem with the question.

Answer (score 18):

No, I don't think this should be removed as a close vote reason. We get a *lot* of questions by lost people asking about support for some software package, their Facebook account, etc. Most of these are terrible, and should not be migrated to Super User. This close reason lets us quickly address those without burdening Super User with our trash.

Perhaps [we could remove the language suggesting they ask over on Super User](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons), but I don't think this close reason should be removed.

Comment: Then the close reason should be changed so that it *doesn't* in effect say "repost this on super user".  Telling the user to repost their question on another site is a *much* worse experience than migrating it there and having the migration rejected.

Comment: @MichaelT `You **may** be able to get help on Super User.` I don't see anywhere where it says they **should** ask there.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 I assure you, that when a question is closed and there is some *hint* of a "go post on this other site" in the off topic reason or comment, the OP *will* go to that other site and paste the exact same question unless there are specific wording informing them that the question will get closed there too with the question as it is currently written.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, do away with the super user close reason. It needs to go as it just confuses migrations. If you are going to migrate a question, migrate it. If you are going to say "go post over there"... well, don't say that.

Closing questions as unclear doesn't give directly actionable information as it is generically written for all of Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow (the same reason exists on Cooking.SE).  Most of these questions are either homework or people trying to get someone else to do their job for them.

From [Is it acceptable to use "Too broad" as a substitute close reason for zero effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288967/is-it-acceptable-to-use-too-broad-as-a-substitute-close-reason-for-zero-effort/288969#288969) :

> I'm of the opinion that [*effort* is generally a poor reason to close questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor), although lack of research is often a great reason to downvote. Homework tends to have other problems as well though: sadly, folks posting their homework verbatim often fail to actually write a question to go along with it, implicitly asking someone to solve a problem that's ill-defined to the satisfaction of someone (the person who assigned the problem) who will neither read it nor be able to clarify any ambiguities present. These can (and should) be closed as unclear what you're asking.

Unclear reads:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

But we can do better with custom text that clearly defines the issue with just giving a problem and giving Stack Overflow specific guidance as to the expectations that unclear glosses over:

The off topic reason should be replaced with:

> Questions that only define a problem without providing the corresponding code, constraints, expectations, and errors cannot be reasonably answered. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the attempted solution and errors.

This is intended to address questions such as:

> Write a function named rotate right that takes as its argument the following: (1) an array of floating point value. (2) an integer that tells the number of cells in the array. The function should shift the contents of each cell one place to the right except the contents of the last cell, which should be moved into the cell with subscript 0. Thus, for example, if the array passed to the function looks like: {5.8,2.6,9.2,3.4,7.0} then when the function returns, the array will have been changed so that it looks like this: {7.0,3.4,9.2,2.6,5.8}. The function should not return value.

Unclear, while applicable to this, doesn't fit well.  It is clear exactly what is being asked, and what is needed... but not as it fits within the context of Stack Overflow.  ... and neither do the other reasons.  But what is clear is that this question *should* be closed and preferably with specific information about what is necessary for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As previously written, your answer was a mis-context quote (you left out the first sentence which contradicts the supposition in your question, that "write code for me" is a reason to close). I edited it to include that context, since otherwise it's treading dangerously close to a misquote.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I am not claiming that a lack of effort is off topic. I am saying that closing the questions that are just problem statements and otherwise would be closed as unclear doesn't give enough information to the OP about how to fix their problem with material from Stack Overflow's help sections.

Comment: They shouldn't be closed as "unclear what you're asking", either.  Only questions that are *actually unclear* should be closed as unclear. If it doesn't actually contain a question, then that's a reason to close.  If a direct list of requirements and rules for software is unclear, then that's a problem with the homework assignment (providing it contains a question).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I've added an actual example question. What should that be closed as? And if the answer is 'unclear', what help does the message in unclear give the poster about how to fix the question?  I know *exactly* what is being asked.  I know *exactly* what the OP needs. There is some hand wavy stuff about "details", but nothing actionable in the unclear off topic text that says specifically how to fix this question.

Comment: The example at the end. There is no problem statement, we have a close reason for that.

Comment: @KevinB what is the close reason for that?

Comment: @MichaelT From your edited answer, it seems like you do have a valid question; but the presupposition in your actual question above keeps it from being clear. You probably want a new meta question that just centers around this; without tangling in other close reasons (Iike close as belongs on superuser, since we use that a lot).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker In the past I have had difficulty in proposing the expansion of close reasons without a corresponding "which one should we remove" (and that was on a site with fewer close reasons than SO has been granted). Thus, the 'remove that one, replace it with this one' proposal. If you are able to add this close reason and activate it *without* deactivating another one, I'll happily redo the meta question. But otherwise, saying "deactivate that one, activate this one" is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelT No doubt there; but you've got to pick one that's either 1) lower value (which SU isn't) or write a proposal to combine two other close reasons (like general hardware and software and IT work/Server Fault) into a reason that says, "This doesn't belong here. If it's about general hardware or software, ask about it on SU, if it's about Hardware and Software from a business perspective, ask about it on SF").

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Having been on the receiving end of a site that gets many "belongs on ..." close reasons and comments, I am *very* hesitant to say that such as a good off topic reason.  Also, while its less work (one less click), it makes it harder to actually migrate the proper questions (from meta.P.SE [on close reasons](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6107/40980) - note the "belongs on SO" which we got by default caused us to have fewer migrations of questions that *do* belong on SO) resulting in a poor user experience and more work for mods (close duplicate) and users (repost).

Comment: ... to that extent, I stand by the "replace the belongs on Super User" suggestion for an off topic reason. You've got a migration target for it. If it belongs on Super User, migrate it. If it doesn't (because it isn't a good question), don't say it belongs on Super User.

Comment: @MichaelT One issue is that some questions could belong on SU if they were better written, but they aren't, so we're definitely not going to migrate them.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker having been on another site that has gotten "belongs on ..." type close and comments I'm going to say that *really* does a disservice to the users and makes the reviewers on the other sites a bit annoyed at the cross posted crap questions. I *still* stand by the "replace the off topic reason wholesale as you've already got the migration avenue open".  Poor questions need to be closed rather than say "you may get help on the other site" without specific information about what the expectations for the other site are.